# I am looking for a font used in Wordpress

Tags: theme-customizer

I am looking for the font used in Wordpress, in the Customizer, describing what theme you are using see my graphic.
[image: Font used in Customizer]

Comment: Use your browser's DOM inspector to see what font is used.

Answer (score 2):

As of core version 4.6 WP went from web fonts back to using system fonts:

> As such, the font stack includes the following:
>
> - -apple-system for Safari (iOS & macOS) and Firefox macOS
> - BlinkMacSystemFont for Chrome macOS
> - Segoe UI for Windows
> - Roboto for Android and Chrome OS
> - Oxygen-Sans for KDE
> - Ubuntu for Ubuntu
> - Cantarell for GNOME
> - Helvetica Neue for versions of macOS prior to 10.11
> - sans-serif, the standard fallback
>
> https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/07/native-fonts-in-4-6/

And exact technical expression/order in CSS as of right now is:

```
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
```

So the actual font you are seeing is highly specific to the system you are looking at it on. You should just use the browser debug tools to check which specific font is being used in the case you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses system fonts as of [version 4.6](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/07/native-fonts-in-4-6/).

You can determine the font used by inspecting the element in Chrome Developer Tools or any modern browser's equivalent:

```
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I found that expression, then it threw me because I thought the same, about system specific, I am looking at this on an iMac using Firefox, so one of these fonts is it?

Comment: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif  any further ideas? thanks guys

Comment: Found a great article and this subject which is very subjective 8-) so, That font depends on system, browser, version OS etc : [link]https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/11/using-system-ui-fonts-practical-guide/